# html5 draggable hide original element

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, html5-draggable

When starting to drag an element using HTML5 draggable attribute, original element is still visible, so I end up having two elements visible instead of one.

How can I do to have only the element being dragged visible (the original one should be momentarily hidden).

```
<script>
  function startDrag() {
    // hide initial element
  }

  function endDrag() {
    // reset initial element
  }
</script>

<div class="draggable" draggable="true"
  ondragstart="startDrag(event)"
  ondragend="endDrag(event)"
></div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle to show the problem https://jsfiddle.net/gjc5p4qp/

Comment: the best hack is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69869851/22957928

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may succeed this with a hacky solution. The native draggability doesn't allow CSS styles like: `opacity:0;`, `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`.

But you can do it using: `transform:translateX(-9999px)`.

```js
function startDrag(e) {
  let element = e.target;
  
  element.classList.add('hide');
}

function endDrag(e) {
  let element = e.srcElement;
  
  element.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
.draggable {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #CC0000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.hide {
  transition: 0.01s;
  transform: translateX(-9999px);
}
```

```html
<div
  class="draggable"
  draggable="true"
  ondragstart="startDrag(event)"
  ondragend="endDrag(event)"
/>
```

I've updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjc5p4qp/2/) with the solution.

**[EDIT]:**

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lvgfu9z/) example with [Andrew Hedges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379184/html5-draggable-hide-original-element/36379727#comment66939298_36385912) suggestion by using `requestAnimationFrame` instead `setTimeout`.

**[EDIT 2]:**

Updated with a better solution by [Jason Yin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65286640/3938676) adding `transition` CSS property instead using `requestAnimationFrame`, it moves the processing from scripting to rendering.

Comment: Wow that's really good, do you know how to set opacity of dragged element to 1 ?

Comment: Haha, thanks. I couldn't find a way to do that, seems the dragged "ghost element" isn't avaible at the DOM, so we get some limitations. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904112/3938676)

Comment: @julesbou Filipe is there still no proper solution to this?

Comment: why do you have to use setTimeout?! it glitches out without it.

Comment: @Anthony after you click the element, the browser 'copies' the element, if the element is hidden the browser will copy a transparent element. The timeout allows the browser to copy and only then hide the element.

Comment: @Filipe thanks, i didn't know that. drag and drop is new to me :)

Comment: @Filipe then wouldn't there be a way to remove the transparency of the "copied" object??

Comment: Transitions with really small durations removes the needs for the timeout if anyone was wondering

Answer (score 17):

This could be achieved without hacky trick from the previous answers.

The key point is to listening to the `drag` event, instead of the `dragstart`.

```js
//listen to drag event, not dragstart!
document.querySelector(".draggable").addEventListener("drag", (e)=>{
  e.target.classList.add("dragging");
});
document.querySelector(".draggable").addEventListener("dragend", (e)=>{
  e.target.classList.remove("dragging");
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:#5856d6;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
}

.dragging {
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #5856d6;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="draggable">Drag me!</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Since simply setting `visibility: hidden` doesn't work, I found another somewhat hacky solution: set `visibility: hidden` one millisecond after the drag event starts.

```js
function startDrag(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }, 1);
}

function endDrag(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.style.visibility = "";
  }, 1);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.draggable {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #CC0000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="startDrag(event)" ondragend="endDrag(event)">

</div>
```

Comment: Rather than use a `setTimeout`, you can use `window.requestAnimationFrame` for this:

`function startDrag(e) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        e.target.style.visibility = "hidden";
      });
    }`

Comment: @AndrewHedges any idea how to prevent the lowering of opacity?!

Comment: @Anthony Have you found a solution for mimicking old way drag and drop (with no original element visible and no opacity in drag copy)?

Comment: @Rantiev yes, you basically have to create your own drag and drop functionality from scratch, and actually move the element which is being moved by the user, which isn't as difficult as it might seem. use `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, `clientX`, `clientY`, etc

Comment: @anthony So, this means we can't mimic, we just have to use old way? I already have it... just had some weird issue with FF, where i had to attach dragstart listener and call e.preventDefault() inside, to prevent drag stucking there. That's why i started to look into the new way (creator of which need to burn in hell forever)

Comment: @Rantiev tbh, im not sure if its possible now. i havent messed around with drag and drop for a while, so...

Answer (score 5):

## How to hide your element

If you want to hide your element, you can use the CSS property [`visibility:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) or [`display:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

I recommend using the `visibility` property because it's hides an element without changing the layout of the document. But, if you're element have childrens and you want to hide them to, you need to set up `visibility:inherit` on each of childrens.

## When to hide it

You were right to use the [`dragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragstart_event) event. But the clone of the element who is created by the draggable attribute appears at the end of the `dragstart` event.

Because JavaScript engine is a single-threaded interpreter if you choose to hide it in here, you're element will be masked as its clone which will copy the property `visibility:hidden`. In fact, to avoid this you need to hide it after the creation of the clone in the [Javascript callstack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack).

To do it, use the [`setTimout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function and set it to 0 ms. This way, the masking of the original element is put at the end of the stack, after the creation of his clone.

At the end of the drag, to make it reappear, you just need to set the element visible by calling `visibility:visible` in the [`dragend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/dragend_event) event.

## Code exemple

For you're exemple, the code can look like this :

```html
<div 
    class="draggable" 
    draggable="true" 
    ondragstart="startDrag(event)" 
    ondragend="endDrag(event)" 
    style="background: #e66465; color:white; width:80px; height:20px; text-align:center;">
    Drag me
</div>

<script>
    function startDrag(e) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            e.target.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }, 0);
    }
    function endDrag(e){
        e.target.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Filipe's answer is really helpful. If `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't work for you. try adding transition.

```css
transition: transform 0.01s;
transform: translateX(-9999px);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your dragStart event this code:

```
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0); // Hide the dragged element
```

It will hide your target dragged element.

Comment: This is an incredibly useful answer and a one liner, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120001/1807542

With a clean solution to hide the source/original element in the dragover handler instead.

```js
var dragging;
function dragstart(e) {
  dragging = $(this);
}

function dragover(e) {
  dragging.hide();
}

function dragend(e) {
  if (dragging) {
    dragging.show();
    dragging = undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: `hide()` and `show()` are jQuery methods